# Can't figure syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end error

Tags: ruby

I get:

```
Untitled 5.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting
keyword_end
```

even though I closed the `if`/`else` statement and `def` with `end`:

```
def max_2_sum(int_collection)
  sum = 0
  if int_collection.empty?
    sum
  else if int_collection.count == 1
    int_collection.first
  else
    sum = int_collection.sort[-1] + int_collection.sort[-2] 
  end
end


int_collection = [4,3,9]    
puts max_2_sum(int_collection)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
else if
```

is wrong. It should be

```
elsif
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like below

```
def max_2_sum(int_collection)
  sum = 0
  if int_collection.empty?
    sum
  elsif int_collection.count == 1
    int_collection.first
  else
     sum = int_collection.sort[-1] + int_collection.sort[-2] 
   end
 end
```